# How to specifiy Hibernate mappings with Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

With Spring Boot 1.x, we could specify hibernate mapping files by extending `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`, overriding `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean and set mapping resources, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060677/2194594).

Since Spring Boot 2.0 (2.0.0.M5 precisly), we can’t do this anymore because `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` has changed (with [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/bd02edf2ce749b70dcc45563bbeec2ab503d875c)) and we can’t extend the `HibernateJpaConfiguration` because it is package protected.

Do you know another way to specify hibernate mapping files using Spring Boot 2.0?

Thanks!

Comment: An issue has been created on Spring Boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10684

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6, rather than overriding Spring Boot's internal, you should use the new **`spring.jpa.mapping-resources`** property for defining custom mappings.

Example in YML:

`spring:
  jpa:
    mapping-resources:
      - db/mappings/dummy.xml`

For a complete example, check the [`application.yml` configuration file of this repository](https://github.com/damienbeaufils/clean-architecture-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml).

Comment: I've been adding mappings dynamically by scanning the classpath, which you can't do with this approach.

Comment: Is it possible to use a wildcard so that individual files don't have to be listed explicitly in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String[] loadResourceNames() {
    Resource[] resources = null;
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        resources = ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader).getResources("classpath: *.hbm.xml");

    
        for ( Resource resource : resources ) {
               names.addAll( Files.list( resource.getFile().toPath() )
                                       .map ( path -> path.getFileName().toString() )
                                       .filter ( p -> p.endsWith( "hbm.xml") )  
                                       .map ( p -> "your directory on class path".concat(p) ) 
                                       .collect ( Collectors.toList() ) );

            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    System.out.println(resources);
    return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
}

@Primary
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql","true");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
    //properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create");
    properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto","create");
    
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("edu.balu.batch.migration.dataloadccp.model.target")
            .properties(new HashMap(properties))
            .mappingResources(loadResourceNames())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Hi Balu. Thanks for your answer. Usually it may be useful to provide few words to explain the solution.