# ORM in deployed WAR file is being ignored

Tags: java, spring, swing, jpa

The setup I have is that I am using Maven to build a Spring API project and generating a .WAR file. This war file is being deployed to a Tomcat server. My setup works locally in Eclipse with no issues or problems, and calls the correct queries/etc. However when I attempt to deploy it to the Tomcat server, I get the following error:

```
        Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findDetails found for type EmployeeInfo!
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94)
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382)
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358)
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311)
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324)
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293)
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
            at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
            at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
            at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
            at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93)
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76)
            ... 96 more
```

I am not sure if we are missing something required to bridge the connection, or there is maybe a setting that is needed. Any assistance is welcome - I have included as many relevant files as I can think of, but let me know if anything else might be required and I will upload it too.

**EmployeeInfoRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeInfo, Integer> {
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
    public List<EmployeeInfo> findDetails(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

**orm.xml** (please note, it is located in src/main/resources/META-INF/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd ">
<named-native-query name="EmployeeInfo.findDetails" result-class="com.place.thing.model.EmployeeInfo">
    <query>SELECT ...  </query>
</named-native-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

**EmployeeInfoController**

```
    @GetMapping("/intake/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeIntakeInfoResponse> getEmployeeInfo(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
List<EmployeeInfo> result = intakeFormRepo.findDetails(id);

if (result.size() != 1) {
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Error Message Here");
}

return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new EmployeeInfoResponse(result.get(0)));
}
```

Comment: @DanW Since `@Query` annotation is used without query string, Spring data is supposed to find the query named `EmployeeInfo.findDetails` and use it. And It does so for OP when it is not deployed as war. But when deployed as war, it is not picking up the query

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai is exactly correct. And the root of all my problems. I should mention I am a novice programmer in relation to the Spring/JPA framework, so its possible I missed something obvious. What bothers me is that it works perfectly in my local environment (Eclipse) but fails when deployed as a WAR.

Comment: I haven't used War deploy for so long. Is there any restriction for you if it can be defined on the top of the entity class?

Comment: Not explicitly, but complex select queries returning into an entity. We could move it into the Query annotation but it's rather large.

Comment: How is your `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` configured?

Comment: @crizzis I do not believe we have one from looking around.

Comment: I understand that you already verified `orm.xml` *does* get copied to the final WAR?

Comment: @crizzis yes - in the deployed war file in the Tomcat server, I have verified both that the file exists and its contents are correct.

Comment: Just to make sure, it is located under `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` directory, right?

Comment: @crizzis Yes! In fact that was something we just recently confirmed. I've placed it in multiple locations but non seem to work.

Comment: Huh, that's funny. You might want to try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060677/1092818) and experiment with different values for the `spring.jpa.orm` property (I'd try with `"META-INF/orm.xml"` first)